# How to set up sqlite to be local server (on lan)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Current situation : I have one GUI program(written by python) which using sqlite data stored on my computer.

Wishlist: I would like to have one server computer to locate sqlite data (DATA A1) (CRUD operation needed) and ten more client computer using GUI program(written by python) which connect with the sqlite data (DATA A1) on lan.

I have no idea how to set up this program and server and what I need to learn more.

Current example code for check product in shop:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

GUI = Tk()
GUI.geometry('1280x720')

def connect_product_data():
    global conn
    global c
    conn = sqlite3.connect('A1.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

def pull_product_data():
    global sqlselectdata
    connect_product_data()
    with conn:
        c.execute("""SELECT * FROM PDLIST""",
            )
    sqlselectdata = c.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    return sqlselectdata

tree_view_frame = Frame(GUI)
tree_view_frame.pack()
tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_view_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

header = ['Part No.', 'Name', 'Price']
hdsize = [70,250,70]
aanchor = [W,W,E]
global product_table
product_table = ttk.Treeview(tree_view_frame, columns = header, show = 'headings', height = 20, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, selectmode="extended")
def treeview_sort_column(product_table, col, reverse):
    l = [(product_table.set(k, col), k) for k in product_table.get_children('')]
    try:
        l.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[0].replace(",","")), reverse=reverse)
    except:
        l.sort(reverse=reverse)
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        product_table.move(k, '', index)
    product_table.heading(col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, not reverse))
for col in header:
    product_table.heading(col, text=col,command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(product_table, _col, False))
product_table.pack()
tree_scroll.config(command = product_table.yview)
for h,s,a in zip(header, hdsize, aanchor):
    product_table.heading(h, text = h)
    product_table.column(h,width = s, anchor = a)

def check_Product():
    A1data = pull_product_data()
    if len(A1data)>0:
        for v in A1data:
            product_table.insert('', 'end', value = (v[0],v[1],v[2]))

B_check_product = ttk.Button(GUI, text = "Add Product", width = 15, command = check_Product)
B_check_product.pack()

GUI.mainloop()
```

changing sqlite3 to MySQL:

```
def connect_product_data():
    global mc
    global conn
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="123456789",
        database="mydatabase"
    )
    mc = conn.cursor()

def pull_product_data():
    global sqlselectdata
    connect_product_data()
    mc.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")
    sqlselectdata = mc.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    return sqlselectdata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.  `Sqlite` is a simple, in-memory, single-process database.  If you need a database server, then use a database server.  There are many choices.

Comment: could you please suggest one which is suitable for my requisition : one server computer, ten client and CRUD operation needed (Free program if it is possible).

Comment: If you want SQL, the primary choices are MySQL and Postgres.  Both are open source, well-supported, and production-quality.

Comment: I'm already try to using MySQL. What should I do next to set up a server?

Comment: Google.  Read.  The answer depends on what operating system you are using, but there are excellent tutorials available.